# POST /token/refresh 401 unauthorized response?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I can't handle this error in my react app when making a post request with refresh token to DRF api. It happens sometimes and I get thousands errors in the console.

This is the function making requests:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:8000/api',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
})


axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      
      if (error.response?.status === 401 && error.response.statusText === "Unauthorized" && 'access_token') {
          const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

          return axiosInstance
              .post('/token/refresh/', {refresh: refresh_token})
              .then((response) => {

                  localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                  localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                  axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + response.data.access;
                  originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + response.data.access;

                  return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                 console.log(err)

              });
      }

      
      return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: My guess is that the POST `/token/refresh/` call is also returning a 401, causing an infinite loop. While it won't immediately fix your issue, you can try to change your interceptor to ignore 401 errors for POST calls to the `/token/refresh/` route while you diagnose the issue on the backend.

Comment: @Moistbobo thank you but I have no idea where the problem on the backend side can be because earlier everything was working fine and I was able to send refresh tokens